Why is Schwarzian derivative "the only" derivative which satisfies $PSL(2,\mathbb{C})$ invariance and vanishes for Mobius transformations?
In Francesco-Senechal's book on CFTs it is said that

In fact, it can be shown that the Schwarzian derivative in $(5.124)$ is the only possible addition to the tensor transfonnation law that satisfies the group property $(5.130)$ and vanishes
for global conformal transformations.

where $(5.124)$ is the usual definition of Schwarzian derivatives
$$ \{w;z\}= \frac{d^3 w/dz^3}{dw/dz}-\frac{3}{2}\left(\frac{d^2 w/dz^2}{dw/dz}\right)\tag{5.124}$$
and $(5.130)$ is the group closure law of $PSL(2,\mathbb{C})$ i.e.
$$\{u;z\}=\{w;z\}+\left(\frac{dw}{dz}\right)^2\{ u;w \}$$. Btw, Global conformal transformations are just $PSL(2, \mathbb{C}))$ transformations in physics literature.
How to prove this statement? I could not find it in physics books, and hope that it is non-trivial. So I am looking for resources on this.

Possibly some relevant references here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/38105/is-there-an-underlying-explanation-for-the-magical-powers-of-the-schwarzian-deri
